# Apply converter to static property in XAML

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

How to set a **converter** for a **static property**? The following example shows my problem – I would like to convert a `TextBlock` text to upper case.

```
<UserControl x:Class="CoRiMaCorporate.HomeScreen.Controls.Home.ConfigurationControl"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             xmlns:mainResources="clr-namespace:MainSharedResources;assembly=MainSharedResources"
             xmlns:converters="clr-namespace:CommonClientLibrary.Converters;assembly=CommonClientLibrary" />
<UserControl.Resource>
    <converters:StringToUpperCaseStringConverter x:Key="stringToUpperCaseStringConverter" />
</UserControl.Resource>
<Grid>
    …
    <TextBlock Text="{x:Static mainResources:Lang.Applications}" />
    …
</Grid>
```

I looking for something like this:

```
<TextBlock Text="{Binding Converter=stringToUpperCaseStringConverter, ConverterParameter={x:Static mainResources:Lang.Applications}}" />
```

Comment: How about `{Binding {x:Static mainResources:Lang.Applications}, Converter=stringToUpperCaseStringConverter}`

Comment: @MikeEason Unfortunately – Expected type is 'PropertyPath', actual type is 'string'.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

static property goes to binding Source, converter provided by StaticResource

```
<TextBlock Text="{Binding Converter={StaticResource stringToUpperCaseStringConverter}, 
                          Source={x:Static mainResources:Lang.Applications}}" />
```

Comment: I was wondering whether this works as well in Xamarin and using `StaticResource` from `App.xaml` instead of `x:Static`. It does work!