# String.Format in XAML without binding

Tags: wpf, xaml

I need to concatenate various combinations of some strings like this:

```
"After doing this and that, press the 'whatever'-button."
```

Therer are multiple combinations possible and to keep it safe in future I wanted to do some kind of

```
String.Format("After doing this and that, press the '{0}'-button.", "whatever");
```

with strings from the strings resources.

All I've found is:

```
<!-- Strings.Temperature contains: "Temperature: {0} °C" --> 
Text="{Binding Temperature, StringFormat={x:Static loc:Strings.Temperature}}" />
```

or even:

```
<TextBlock.Text>
    <!-- Strings.Temperature contains: "Temperature: {0} °C / {1} °F" --> 
    <MultiBinding StringFormat=StringFormat={x:Static loc:Strings.Temperature}>
        <Binding Path="{Binding TemperatureCelcius}" />
        <Binding Path="{Binding TemperatureFahrenheit}" />
    </MultiBinding>
</TextBlock.Text>
```

but I don't have a binding to the "value" string. It is also a static variable. And I know I could really bind it to some viewmodel string property but I didn't want to produce so much overhead in different viewmodels.

Any ideas?

Comment: another similar case: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42159000/xaml-converter-for-static-resource, replace Converter -> StringFormat

Comment: Okay thanks! That was one of those cases where I just couldn't find the Right key words. As you see, I did some Research and found many results that all used binding..